# Adding html divs to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML DIVs that retain user's shipping information. I'm creating a way of copying their info into the billing section if they so wish, but to also make sure they actually copy something rather than a empty field. My check code actually works but I want to avoid having to check each of the divs like the way I've had.

Is there a way of adding all these divs to an array and iterating and checking through the array?

```js
document.querySelector('#sameAsBilling').addEventListener('click', checkEmpty);

function checkEmpty() {
  var shippingName = document.getElementById('shipping_firstname').value;
  if (shippingName === "") {
    jQuery("#shipping_firstname").attr("placeholder", "ENTER DETAILS HERE");
    document.getElementById("shipping_firstname").style["border-color"] = "red";
    document.getElementById("shipping_firstname").scrollIntoView();
    document.getElementById("sameAsBilling").checked = false;
    return;
  }
  jQuery("#shipping_firstname").attr("placeholder", "");
  showHideShipping();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_firstname">[CustomerInfo_firstname]</label>
  <input name="shipping_firstname" onchange="clearContent(this);" type="text" id="shipping_firstname" value="[shipping_firstname]" size="15" tabindex="16" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_firstname-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_firstname-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_lastname">[CustomerInfo_lastname]</label>
  <input name="shipping_lastname" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="shipping_lastname" value="[shipping_lastname]" size="15" tabindex="17" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_lastname-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_lastname-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_company">[CustomerInfo_company]</label>
  <input name="shipping_company" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="shipping_company" value="[shipping_company]" size="25" tabindex="18" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_address">[CustomerInfo_address]</label>
  <input name="shipping_address" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);[po_box_disabled_billing]" id="shipping_address" value="[shipping_address]" size="25" tabindex="20" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_address-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_address-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_address2">[CustomerInfo_address2]</label>
  <input name="shipping_address2" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="shipping_address2" value="[shipping_address2]" size="25" tabindex="21" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_city">[CustomerInfo_city]</label>
  <input name="shipping_city" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="shipping_city" value="[shipping_city]" size="25" tabindex="22" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_city-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_city-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_country">[CustomerInfo_country]</label>
  <select name="shipping_country" onchange="this.form.shipping_zip.value='';populateState('shipping_state','shipping_country');check_stateValidator('billing');check_address('billing');" tabindex="23" class="txtBoxStyle" id="shipping_country">
  </select>
  <!--START: req_shipping_country-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_country-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_phone">[CustomerInfo_phone]</label>
  <input name="shipping_phone" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="shipping_phone" value="[shipping_phone]" size="25" tabindex="19" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_phone-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_phone-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet. Please make it run. Also why use `addEventListener` and `document.getElementById('shipping_firstname')` if you have jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function checkEmpty() {
    var ok = true;
    $('.check-field').each(function(index, field) { 
        var $field = $(field);

        if (!$field.val()) { // Invalid field
            ok = false;
            $field
                .attr("placeholder", "ENTER DETAILS HERE")
                .css("border-color", "red");

            field.scrollIntoView();
        }
        else { // Valid field. Resets the style.
            $field
                .attr("placeholder", "")
                .css("border-color", "");
        }
    });

    $("#sameAsBilling").prop("checked", (ok ? "checked" : false));
    showHideShipping();
}
```

I didn't tested it actually, so forgive me for any typo or syntax error. The thing is that you need to add a class named `check-field` to every element you want to check. The snippet will loop through all of them and check the value, change the border color and placeholder whenever it has error or not. So all invalid elements will be styled as invalid at same time, instead of one-by-one.

Comment: Disregard what i said. I#m an idiot, thankyou for the answer!

Comment: One thing i've notice is the checkbox does not reset itself when there is an error

Comment: @JohnDoi2021 I'm not sure the behaviour of the checkbox, but I have updated the question with a better control of it. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues. I have tried to fix a number of them

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sameAsBilling').on('click', checkEmpty);
  
  /*
  $("[name^=shipping]").on("input",function() {
    if ($.trim(this.value)==="") {
      this.value = "placeholders make more sense";
    }
  }); 
  */  
});
function checkEmpty() {
  var $shippingFN = $('#shipping_firstname');
  var shippingName = $shippingFN.val();
  if (shippingName === "") {
    $shippingFN.attr("placeholder", "ENTER DETAILS HERE");
    $shippingFN.css({"border-color":"red"});
    $shippingFN[0].scrollIntoView();
    $("#sameAsBilling").prop("checked",false);
    return;
  }
  else $shippingFN.attr("placeholder", "");
  //showHideShipping();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_firstname">[CustomerInfo_firstname]</label>
  <input name="shipping_firstname" type="text" id="shipping_firstname" value="[shipping_firstname]" size="15" tabindex="16" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_firstname-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_firstname-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_lastname">[CustomerInfo_lastname]</label>
  <input name="shipping_lastname" type="text" id="shipping_lastname" value="[shipping_lastname]" size="15" tabindex="17" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_lastname-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_lastname-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_company">[CustomerInfo_company]</label>
  <input name="shipping_company" type="text" id="shipping_company" value="[shipping_company]" size="25" tabindex="18" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

Same <input type="checkbox" id="sameAsBilling" />

<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_address">[CustomerInfo_address]</label>
  <input name="shipping_address" type="text"  id="shipping_address" value="[shipping_address]" size="25" tabindex="20" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_address-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_address-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_address2">[CustomerInfo_address2]</label>
  <input name="shipping_address2" type="text" id="shipping_address2" value="[shipping_address2]" size="25" tabindex="21" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_city">[CustomerInfo_city]</label>
  <input name="shipping_city" type="text"   id="shipping_city" value="[shipping_city]" size="25" tabindex="22" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_city-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_city-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_country">[CustomerInfo_country]</label>
  <select name="shipping_country" onchange="this.form.shipping_zip.value='';populateState('shipping_state','shipping_country');check_stateValidator('billing');check_address('billing');" tabindex="23" class="txtBoxStyle" id="shipping_country">
  </select>
  <!--START: req_shipping_country-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_country-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div class="chkField">
  <label for="shipping_phone">[CustomerInfo_phone]</label>
  <input name="shipping_phone" type="text" onchange="clearContent(this);" id="shipping_phone" value="[shipping_phone]" size="25" tabindex="19" class="txtBoxStyle" />
  <!--START: req_shipping_phone-->
  <img src="assets/templates/common/images/error2.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="" />
  <!--END: req_shipping_phone-->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```